# How to interpret the probability of a negative value in a density plot

Tags: r, probability, ggplot2

I have the following density plot in R using `ggplot`

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- structure(list(Key = c("one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", 
"one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", 
"one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", 
"one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", 
"one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", 
"one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", 
"one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", 
"one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", 
"one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", 
"two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", 
"two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", 
"two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", 
"two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", 
"two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", 
"two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", 
"two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", 
"two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", 
"two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two"), Value = c(0.175593676865012, 
1.00644104924411, -0.190162807356439, -0.888588927537778, 1.05003919376752, 
1.55232989686702, 1.34603452484798, -0.0433397188589121, 1.18178777152845, 
-1.11260056381902, 0.0297985945767294, -0.885399688951585, -0.709032710358359, 
1.53559296822897, -0.361365779931032, -1.04110474718347, -0.160848705487698, 
-0.709032759726326, -0.624704445259604, 0.148001124537848, 0.141143330361308, 
-0.165441291398811, -0.253533146544934, 0.805191673125886, 0.32738354982533, 
-0.214906302424514, 0.274543768604771, -0.244376791070368, 0.217498124241821, 
0.638139819792139, 1.7852979741844, 0.816559357822799, -0.433845457580582, 
-0.152071652673642, 0.140755600620382, 0.593629822044398, -0.478510193519338, 
0.517289718674834, -1.42289962829009, 0.0856817641595347, -0.516676256793157, 
0.549715821674557, 0.548605531029533, -0.668319728512709, 0.999421510970335, 
-0.0360925768253821, -0.173307938997241, 0.0231410260412118, 
0.580596732727313, -0.877337411354812, -0.0346882218578643, 0.493904016397451, 
0.146063625584083, -0.565833202070975, 0.550984512275854, -0.354293914206467, 
-0.284157559258815, -0.998376513782123, 0.316835884128646, 0.0675519066542234, 
-0.301148528038494, 1.0756086542837, -0.0412222157623601, -0.453480177418225, 
-0.121440083145342, 1.36919854136863, -1.5527836032271, -0.739198934481022, 
-0.012283131026879, 0.114363526035302, -0.436722798760769, 0.181000102909766, 
0.215297307599415, -1.36681083726189, -0.690223438593125, -0.19944964145332, 
-0.169832902365242, -0.91557707043544, 0.106486820069749, 0.440361128770158, 
-0.559676983505271, -1.00489321690941, 0.452828512779074, 2.16419889805465, 
0.634033804085108, 0.427303879515914, 1.25415995135624, -1.32033800109243, 
-1.00761177208776, -1.46946638819998, -1.44170533907693, 0.757942524155521, 
-0.185789974907883, -0.66379708392503, 0.67327296186599, -0.530431219677827, 
-0.427074294342673, -0.172224315297597, 0.0918788126952378, -0.400867777328158, 
0.100815808252484, 0.631028784898851, 0.230283895821093, -0.257409325114271, 
0.508896568816297, 0.32720337639953, 0.898285527052061, 0.747852945931738, 
0.328079741373721, 1.03171449561824, -1.07253807546541, 0.132906452372606, 
0.192934565224844, -0.25568986850564, -0.485622401533653, 0.0316498131007403, 
-0.357280677795209, -0.253724880719589, 0.0859533289368766, 0.298991261557629, 
0.256144141088495, 0.0428644832140026, 0.357824845669414, -0.294411831000571, 
-0.157216001196747, -0.229076499006184, 1.18109276026226, -0.564796151975511, 
-0.417545051084053, 0.653323493909632, -0.155557286946467, 0.492104541064074, 
-0.109517960138712, 0.013472132541389, -0.641712175123785, -0.589029622272586, 
1.19293826273643, -0.281353971462309, -0.422218300493346, 0.873692309220974, 
0.0679824914231842, -0.349385913991171, 0.159479051076063, 0.179475017230708, 
-0.825206295403621, -0.154171466507741, 0.450458186841295, -0.340041816795303, 
-0.142473949203032, 0.103042299869743, 0.113832564628563, -0.934892741328337, 
0.429362992658455, -0.246404112864288, -0.18675284876384, -0.170278397106997
)), row.names = c(NA, -156L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(data , aes(x = Value,y = ..scaled.., fill = Key)) +
  geom_density(stat = 'density', alpha = 0.3)
```

I'm interested in calculating the probability of a value in each time series being negative, which I understand would be the total area under the curve up until 0. Is there a way to calculate the total area under the point up until x = 0?

[image]

Comment: Are the values prohibited from being negative for some reason?

Comment: @DemetriPananos no, I'm just interested in visualising the probability of a value being negative in my time series so I'm trying to find out how to interpret that from the chart

Answer (score 0):

Actually that plot is kind of an approximation of your sample data. If you run the code below you will get a much more intuitive version of your case.

```
truehist(df[which(df["Key"]=="one"),"Value"], prob=TRUE, col="lightblue", nbins=15)
lines(density(df[which(df["Key"]=="one"),"Value"]))
abline(v = 0, col="red", lwd=3)
```

The resulting plot is:

[image]

You could interpret the probability of a value in time series "one" being negative as $P(X<0) \approx \sum_{i=1}^{n} base_i * height_i$ where $n$ is the number of negative data points in time series "one". The same idea can be applied to the time series "two".